# Can I use istio for services which access by nodeport in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

**Question**

I create two deployment in kubernetes with the same service which type is NodePort,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: devo-159239e607c694e08b146c855b393652
  namespace: devo-bsg-dev
  labels:
    app: devo
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http-app
    nodePort: 31012
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: devo-159239e607c694e08b146c855b393652
  type: NodePort
```

I can access my service by NodePort and kiali show traffic too

[image]

Then I want all traffic go to version v1, so I create an virtualservice and destinationrule,

```
[root@master104 beego2]# cat beego2-virtual-service.yml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: devo-159239e607c694e08b146c855b393652
  namespace: devo-bsg-dev
spec:
  hosts:
  - devo-159239e607c694e08b146c855b393652
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: devo-159239e607c694e08b146c855b393652
        subset: v1
[root@master104 beego2]# cat beego2-destination.yml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: devo-159239e607c694e08b146c855b393652
  namespace: devo-bsg-dev
spec:
  host: devo-159239e607c694e08b146c855b393652
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2
```

but the result does not show as expected

The  question is: Is my rules wrong or istio can not work with nodeport ?

**Environment**

> kubernetes 1.13.3
>
> istio 1.1.2

Comment: Your approach doesn't seem to be right.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any [Gateway](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/gateway/) configuration within your Istio setup. Istio Gateway represents External IP address in front of Kuberentes microservices that allows incoming traffic through specified ports, protocol and hosts. You can use default `istio-ingressgateway` in the general Gateway resource definition, and then bind corresponded `VirtualService`, i.e.:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: http-gateway
  namespace: devo-bsg-dev
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway #Default Istio Ingressgateway controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - devo-159239e607c694e08b146c855b393652
---

kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: devo-159239e607c694e08b146c855b393652
  namespace: devo-bsg-dev
spec:
  hosts:
  - devo-159239e607c694e08b146c855b393652
  gateways:
  - http-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: devo-159239e607c694e08b146c855b393652
        subset: v1
```

In the above scenario, we want to allow HTTP traffic on Port 80, for host `devo-159239e607c694e08b146c855b393652`.

You can find more related practical materials about exposing Kubernetes micro services via Istio mesh within demo Booking application [example](https://istio.io/docs/examples/bookinfo/).